# How to set thumbnail for iOS share sheet via website?

Tags: ios, share, ios13, navigator

I am trying to figure out how I display a thumbnail for the share sheet in iPhone ( i have attached an image for the icon I am referring to). This feature seems to be available only from ios 13. I am not sure where the image/icon is picked up from. I have correctly set up a path for favicon and og:image on the website however the image is not getting picked up.

Currently, for the path I am using `/assets/favicon.ico` for icon and og:image. Should the image be `www.domain-name.com//assests/favicon.ico`?. I have not been able to find any documentation from the apple part on this.

For navigator.share, it does not have any specifics for sharing icons we can only pass text, URL, description, and files and I do believe navigator.share is not responsible for the image. The image/icon should be picked up from the icon or og:image.

Any suggestion or hint is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If configured properly, I doubt if it is because of cache that you don't see the correct result. Have you tried to clean the cache or have you tried to clean the cdn if your site is cached on the cdn?

Comment: There is no cache as of now, is a WIP site. However, this issue persists while testing locally too. Do you have any suggestions to test it? Also curious where does it pick up the image from, i cannot find the documentation.

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML maybe it will provide you some hint, also from my personal experience. If I deployed the react project with the public folder configured properly. The favicon won't cause any trouble. So I wonder how you deploy your project.

Comment: @zhoujialei, thanks i found the solution and it does not look good

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the solution after a bit of hit and try.

The problem:

> I wanted to display a thumbnail (pick up from the website) for ios 13 devices while I use the native share feature.

Expectation:

> Whenever I use the native share from the browser and display the title and text along with the image

Code:

```
const title = 'Website Name'
const text = 'Welcome to the website'
const url = 'beer_and_melons.com'
    
navigator.share ( {title,text,url});
```

Limitation:
If I want to display the website logo, I cannot pass text field. i.e

```
navigator.share ({url})
```

This way the crawler will go through your site and pick up the icon (**not og:image**)

Conclusion:

> You cannot use text and image together, you need to compormise !

The  following is an image, **note i have not added any text**
[image]

The following is an image with **text field**
[image]

Hope this helps someone and doesnot waste's entire day trying to find a solution!

May the force be with you!